# Sql trigger is not firing on Update, why

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I want to save the changes happened in Customer table into another table Notification in SQL Server 2008. For this i have written the following trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [CustomerNotifier]
                         ON [dbo].[Customer]
                         AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
                         AS
                         BEGIN
                            DECLARE @Action as char(1);
                            SET @Action = (CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INSERTED)
                                                  AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM DELETED)
                                                    THEN 'U'  -- Set Action to Updated.
                                                WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INSERTED)
                                                    THEN 'I'  -- Set Action to Insert.
                                                WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM DELETED)
                                                    THEN 'D'  -- Set Action to Deleted.
                                                ELSE NULL     -- Skip. It may have been a 'failed delete'.   
                                          END)

                            IF @Action = 'I'
                            BEGIN
                                INSERT INTO Notification (CustomerId, BookingId, [Type], [Read], TenantId, TenantUsername, CreatedDateTime)
                                SELECT CustomerId, null, 0, 0, TenantId, AspNetUsers.UserName, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP FROM inserted
                                JOIN AspNetUsers ON  inserted.TenantId = AspNetUsers.Id;
                            END
                            ELSE IF @Action = 'U'
                            BEGIN
                                INSERT INTO Notification (CustomerId, BookingId, [Type], [Read], TenantId, TenantUsername, CreatedDateTime)
                                SELECT CustomerId, null, 1, 0, TenantId, AspNetUsers.UserName, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP FROM inserted
                                JOIN AspNetUsers ON  inserted.TenantId = AspNetUsers.Id;
                            END
                            ELSE IF @Action = 'D'
                            BEGIN
                                INSERT INTO Notification (CustomerId, BookingId, [Type], [Read], TenantId, TenantUsername, CreatedDateTime)
                                SELECT CustomerId, null, 1, 0, TenantId, AspNetUsers.UserName, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP FROM deleted
                                JOIN AspNetUsers ON  deleted.TenantId = AspNetUsers.Id;
                            END
                         END
```

The trigger is executing successfully when customer Inserted or Deleted form the Customer table, but the trigger is not executing on Update.

*May be i know the reason: It is not executing because we are updating the entry in another table AspNetUsers which is linked with Customer table by a shared primary key relationship.*

So my question is what should i do to execute this trigger on Update ??

Comment: If question is not clear then please ask for clarification

Answer (score 0):

A trigger will only fire if there was a corrsponding DML on the table the trigger is defined on.

To execute the trigger here you should either create a trigger on the `AspNetUsers` table where the actual update is happening, or update the `Customer` table. Bear in mind that `inserted` and `deleted` pseudo-tables will have data for the table the trigger is defined on.